# How to find confidence level of OCR text extracted using tesseract in java?

Tags: java, tesseract, unsatisfiedlinkerror, tess4j, tess-two

```
import java.io.File;
import com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI;
public class ConfidenceLevelFinder 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        TessBaseAPI baseApi=new TessBaseAPI();
        baseApi.setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PageSegMode.PSM_SINGLE_BLOCK);
        baseApi.setImage(new File("zoomed.jpg"));
        baseApi.meanConfidence();

        baseApi.end();
    }
}
```

1. I am using above code.
2. Using com.googlecode.tesseract.android.TessBaseAPI; library
3. But geeting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lept in java.library.path
4. Which dll is needed for this using tesseract android jar?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please fix the problem in your last point (5). Also post the error trace.

Comment: Which platform are you developing for? Windows? Android?

Comment: Try using the Tess4J project. The com.googlecode.tesseract.android.* classes are for Android only.

Comment: okay. @rmtheis can you provide code to determine Confidence level of output OCR text generated by tesseract?

Comment: The code to do that will be specific to the library that you end up using, so no, not without more info.